# iOS App is >20x slower after building with Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, performance, simd

I have an app (Xcode project) that I developed for iOS 12 (with Xcode 10, Swift 4.2) which I now want to rebuild for iOS 13 using Xcode 11.

When I opened the project in Xcode 11, built and run the project, I found that my app was suddenly more than 20 times slower! I checked multiple times that Release configuration was selected and that the same compile flags were used as in Xcode 10. Needless to say, compiler optimisations are maxed out, just like in Xcode 10.

The app uses a lot of SIMD operations (`float4`, `float3`, `float4x4`, etc.) and works with pointers (e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer<float4>`). I found that Xcode 11 showed me that simd types like [`float4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/float4) are now deprecated and `typealias`ed to new [`SIMD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/simd_vector_types) structs.

Is there something obvious I should know about porting from iOS 12 to iOS 13? Can this change of SIMD types be the source of such terrible decrease in performance? How do I restore the original speeds (iOS 13 seems like a downgrade)?

Comment: Can you produce a simple [mcve] with just one hot loop that shows the perf regression?  Then include the generated asm for the old/new versions so people with asm experience can tell you if that's the reason.  Changing how SIMD types are defined could easily be correlated with compiling them to much worse asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes sadly, I don't have time to extract M(n)WE from my codebase, but based on my solution, it is clear that it's indeed Swift 5's new SIMD wrappers that hinder the performance. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I rewrote the SIMD-heavy Swift codebase to Objective-C, the old performance was restored. Objective-C thankfully still uses the good old SIMD data types without pointless wrappers.

The performance correlates with changes in Swift's implementation of SIMD. In Xcode 10.1 and older, Swift used built-in SIMD data types. With Xcode 10.2 (and newer), Apple added useless [Object-Oriented wrapper](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0229-simd.md) for SIMD data types (e.g. `float3` is typealias for `SIMD4<Float>`) and operations and didn't even bother to test the performance, which made my code more than **20x slower**.

Sometimes you just need speed, don't force Protocol-oriented design where it doesn't belong to.

It doesn't matter if you choose to use Swift 4 or target iOS 12 in Xcode 10.2 and newer, you'll still get the same, bad SIMD performance.

**TL;DR:** Apple messed-up pre-Swift-5 SIMD levels of performance [in Xcode 10.2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2?language=objc) and newer. Port your SIMD-heavy code to Objective-C to get good old levels performance (>20x faster in my case). Let's hope Apple doesn't touch Objective-C or we're soon going to write in Neon assembly to get decent performance...

Comment: Having the same bad speed in objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

My money is on Xcode 11. Apple probably changed the compiler, or compiler settings, in a way that affected the generation of matrix math instructions.

Apple's major releases of Xcode definitely break stuff sometimes, and it can take a while for them to sort it out.

Try building for iOS 12 while using Xcode 11. Then take the same project and build it from Xcode 10.2.

My company's app is HUGE, and build times went up by ≈3X under Xcode 11. It's quite painful. That's a different issue than execution speed, obviously, but it still tells you that there we big changes to the build process.

Comment: I tried building for iOS 12 and 13, but sadly, I couldn't see any difference. Is there no other way of using Neon SIMD instructions?

Comment: Oh, I don't think I understood well — do you suggest to let Xcode 11 generate the project (by targeting iOS 12) and then use Xcode 10's compiler to make a proper, fast build?

Comment: Yes, see if it's Xcode 11 or iOS 13. Switch back to targeting iOS 12 and see if it's slow. If so, take that same project and clean and build it using Xcode 10. If the same project, targeted for iOS 12, runs fast when build with Xcode 10, and runs slowly when built with Xcode 11, that implicates Xcode 11. I would then create a minimum example project (like a float4x4 matrix math benchmark) and submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I tried building the app with Xcode 10.2.1 (I needed to add iOS 13.3 [Device Support](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)), but the app was still slow. Then I tried Xcode 10.1 (also added Device Support for iOS 13.3) and the app was as fast as the original one! Edit: in both cases I targeted iOS 12, so the problem seems to be introduced in Xcode 10.2.1 and newer.

Comment: Interestingly, when I "Jump to Definition…" of `float4` in Xcode 10.2.1, I see the `SIMD4<Float>` typealias nonsense. When I do the same in Xcode 10.1, I can see the good old `public struct float4` declaration. Based on this observation, I think the slowdown is really due to the useless `SIMD4<Float>` redesign. Why did they have to change working system…? Is there any way to force-use the old definitions of SIMD types in newer Xcodes?